# What are the ways of creating objects which depends on string value?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have different types of providers. This providers supplying data from different sources. Also i have a table in the database in which i can find provider to use for specific team.

Team 1 - "FirstProvider"

Team 2 - "SecondProvider" and so on.

Depending on the team i want to use appropriate provider to get specific data for the team.

```
string providerType = ...
IProvider provider;
if(providerType == "FirstProvider") 
{
    provider = new FirstProvider();
} 
else if(providerType == "SecondProvider")
{
    provider = new FirstProvider;
}
```

What is the best patter/way of doing this? Maybe some objects factory...

Comment: research the strategy pattern

Comment: Did you read anything about design patterns? The pattern which you can use here is the most explained and simplest creational pattern to implement. Please read. You will get to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dictionary of anonymous builder methods

In this pattern, we declare a Dictionary where:

- the key is the provider name string
- the value is a Func object (a method that has no parameters and returns a value of type IProvider)

```cs
static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IProvider>> providerBuilderMap =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<IProvider>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    {"firstProviderName",()=> { return new FirstProvider(); } }
};
```

The above declaration:

- declares a `readonly` Dictionary object, to indicate that this object is a read-only reference (and should not change)
- (optionally) includes the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter to make key comparison case **in**sensitive
- initialises the Dictionary with key-value-pairs as required
- the value is an anonymous method that returns an object that implements `IProvider`

We can the use this dictionary to create the objects we require:

```cs
static IProvider GetProviderUsingTypeBuilder(string name)
{
    Func<IProvider> providerBuilder = null;
    if(providerBuilderMap.TryGetValue(name, out providerBuilder))
    {
        return providerBuilder();
    }

    // Choose to throw an exception or return a null value
    //throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("name", "Provider not found.");
    return null;
}
```

## Dictionary of Type

In this pattern, we declare a Dictionary where:

- the key is the provider name string
- the value is simply the `Type` of the instance that we will need to create

```cs
static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> providerTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    { "firstProviderName",typeof(FirstProvider)}
};
```

We will need to use reflection to create instances of the objects we require. This is arguably more expensive than the first pattern (Dictionary of anonymous builder methods):

```
static IProvider GetProviderUsingTypeConstructor(string name)
{
    Type providerType = null;
    if (providerTypeMap.TryGetValue(name, out providerType))
    {
        var constructor = providerType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        return (IProvider)constructor.Invoke(null);
    }

    //throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("name", "Provider not found.");
    return null;
}
```

Note that in the above method, we obtain and invoke a parameterless constructor for the `providerType`. A run-time exception will occur if a parameterless constructor does not exist.

### Note on `readonly Dictionary`

The `providerBuilderMap` and `providerTypeMap` objects used in above examples are readonly. However, the elements of the Dictionary objects are not read-only. If required, we can prevent elements from being added or removed by changing the declaration to ReadOnlyDictionary. For example:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<IProvider>> providerBuilderMap = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<IProvider>>(
    new Dictionary<string, Func<IProvider>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    {"firstProviderName",()=> { return new FirstProvider(); } }
});
```